# Setting Dynamic Env variable in Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

I am trying to set dynamic env variable in Docker but somehow it resets.
I want to set an ENV variable which has value :

```
export EC2_Region=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone)
```

so i cant just use `ENV` in `Dockerfile` since its not static.

I tried making an init.sh and used `CMD["init.sh"]` in `Dockerfile` but when i attach to the docker process, the env variable is empty.

I am fairy new to docker and still exploring options.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I have also tried to replace .bash_profile & source it from init.sh script, but no luck

Comment: Does `docker run --build-arg` may do what you want? https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/

Answer (score 0):

You can use ENTRYPOINT instead of CMD.

Example Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
COPY init.sh /
RUN chmod +x /init.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/init.sh"]
```

init.sh:

```
export EC2_Region=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone)
```

Comment: Does not work for some reason. I tried it. There is no ENV var with this name which is set.

Comment: can you pls provide your Dockerfile and init script. The above Dockerfile and init script worked for me.

Comment: I was able to make it work by placing the .sh script in /etc/profile.d/ to make the env variable persist. with the approach you mentioned above, the env variable was not accessible to the service i was starting.